# Calculating a percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, division, percentage

I'm trying to calculate a percentage in SQL.  I want to find out to get the percentage of output start with 'RT @'

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    ([tweet] varchar(130))    ;

INSERT INTO temp
    ([tweet])
VALUES
    ('WillyWonka'),
    ('Barbara'),
    ('JoanOfArcJoanArcadia'),
    ('LisaDLisa Diddle'),
    ('LisaDSkip Padington'),
    ('WillyNillySiil Stoinson'),
    ('RT @Barbara'),
    ('JoanOfArcJoanArcadia'),
    ('LisaDLisa Diddle'),
    ('RT @LisaDSkip Padington')
;
```

My code returns the lines correctly that I want to see but how do i calculate the percentage of those lines from the total output ... I know its something with selecting the two parts and dividing them but i can't get that right.

```
select count(*) 
from temp
where tweet like 'RT @%'
```

or

```
select * 
from temp
where tweet like 'RT @%'
```

I've read a few of the other posts and am no closer to getting the output. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `conditional Aggregate` to find the percentage of output start with `'RT @'`

```
SELECT ( Count(CASE WHEN tweet LIKE 'RT @%' THEN 1 END) 
                     / Cast(Count(*) AS NUMERIC(10, 2)) ) * 100
FROM   temp
```

Comment: That keeps coming back with 0 value as well. Based on my temp data it should come back with .2 or 20%

Comment: @Elizabeth - Updated check now. due to integer division it avoids the decimal part converting the divisor to decimal value will fix the problem

Comment: bingo! what did you end up doing. What is NUMERIC do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a subquery to find the dividend. Something like this.

```
select (count(t.*) / (select count(*) from temp)) as percentage
from temp t
where tweet like 'RT @%'
```

Comment: That seems to be coming back with 0 (i even added a * 100 into that for the percent output) but that still seems to be coming back with 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp WHERE tweet LIKE 'RT @%') /
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS MONEY FROM temp)) * 100
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening or why all the output is coming back with a zero value but this too is giving me a 0.

Comment: @Elizabeth, because we must cast one of the argument to decimal type. I've edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (CONVERT(DECIMAL, COUNT(CASE WHEN tweet LIKE 'RT @%' THEN 1 END)) / COUNT(1)) * 100
FROM temp
```